# Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" AjaxPro AjaxMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxpro

I am using AjaxPro. I am getting this error while calling `GetReturns()`:

> Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"

```
Report.Areas_Report.GetReturns(30, aoData, (response) => {
  if (response.error == null) {
    var myObject = response.value;
    fnCallback(myObject);
  } else {
    $.growl.error({ 
      message: "An error occurred. Please try again." 
    });
  }
  $(_overlayElementId).remove();
});
```

```csharp
[AjaxMethod]
public DataTableResult GetReturns(int days, List<DataTableAjaxPostModel> model = null)
{
  var dataTableRequest = DataTableModelBinder.FilterDateTableRequest(model);
  var result = reportsService.GetReturns(warehouseId, days, dataTableRequest);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue caused by an update in Chrome.  Unfortunately, the AjaxPro build hasn't been updated to reflect this.  There is still a simple way to get it to work through.  You just need to have your own version of AjaxPro and remove the offending line from the code.

You can download the AjaxPro codebase from Github at https://github.com/michaelschwarz/Ajax.NET-Professional.  You'll need to select download as zip, extract the files, copy the project to your solution, then change your web project's reference to AjaxPro to come from this new project.

Next, open the file in the root of that project called core.js and go to line 445.  The whole block that causes the problem will need to be deleted or commented out.

```
    if(!MS.Browser.isIE) {
        this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    }
```

Save the file, build and the error will be gone.  Note that you don't need to upload the core.js file as it's an embedded resource, it's just the new AjaxPro.dll that will need to be put online.

One further note, this project builds as AjaxPro.dll rather than the newer name of AjaxPro.2.dll despite being the correct version for the .net framework 2+ - you can either change the build name or just change the name in your web.config file.  So for example

```
    <sectionGroup name="ajaxNet">
        <section name="ajaxSettings" type="AjaxPro.AjaxSettingsSectionHandler,AjaxPro.2" requirePermission="false" restartOnExternalChanges="true"/>
    </sectionGroup>
```

will become

```
    <sectionGroup name="ajaxNet">
        <section name="ajaxSettings" type="AjaxPro.AjaxSettingsSectionHandler,AjaxPro" requirePermission="false" restartOnExternalChanges="true"/>
    </sectionGroup>
```

...and everywhere else in the config file that mentions AjaxPro.2 will need to be changed to AjaxPro